# Error SMTP Failed to connect to server

Tags: php

Trato de enviar un email a traves de PHPMailer, pero no hay manera de conseguirlo, tengo este código que deberia ir, y no funciona

Me da el error SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2020-05-23 22:44:52 SMTP connect() failed.

He visto que a mucha gente le pasa, pero no encuentro solución, hay que abrir puertos? alguna extension?

```
    require './correo/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
        require './correo/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "password";
        $mail->SetFrom("email@gmail.com");
        $mail->Subject = "Test";
        $mail->Body = "hello";
        $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
           echo "Message has been sent";
        }
```

Comment: Parece que estás usando el servidor de salida de gmail. Recuerda que debes de habilitar una funcionalidad dentro de la configuración del correo de gmail que permite ocupar el email para envíos externos como phpmailer. Lee más sobre esto aquí: https://www.hostinger.mx/tutoriales/como-usar-el-servidor-smtp-gmail-gratuito/

Comment: Pon 3 por aqui `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1` y te puede mostrar mas informacion

Answer (score 0):

Mira yo en PHP lo mando de esta manera. Esto es de un proyecto de ara un año o asi y me esta funcionando bien.

```
function sendmail($tipoInscripcion, $emailuser, $inscripcion){
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php");

    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php";
        require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
        require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try{
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to
            $mail->Host = "mail.servidorcorreo.com";  // specify main and backup server
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
            $mail->Username = "usuario@servidorcorreo.com";  // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = "Contraseña";
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->From = "Dirección de correo que envia";
            $mail->FromName = "Un nombre";        // remitente
            $mail->AddAddress($emailuser);        // destinatario
            $mail->IsHTML(true);     // set email
            $mail->Body = "EL cuerpo del mensage en html";
            if(!$mail->Send()) 
            {
                exit;
            }
        }catch(phpmailerException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya lo he podido arreglar, era el antivirus avast que lo bloqueaba.
Los pasos a seguir son

Entrar a la aplicacion Avast ->Proteccion -> click a la rueda de la derecha -> Proteccion -> Configurar Opciones de escudo -> Escudo de correo electronico ->deshabilitar las pestaña  "Analizar correos electronicos salientes (SMTP)".

Con esto  y el código de arriba ha funconado